# Fast pseudo shuffling of large arrays

Tags: deep-learning, shuffle

I have a large array of samples that I want to feed into my deep learning model. The shuffling the array takes a long time. I don't need a perfectly random shuffle and given the nature of the problem I don't care about few collisions in the outcome. So, is there a pseudo-shuffling algorithm that is fast and memory efficient?

Comment: How are you shuffling it currently ? Which language / platform ?

Comment: I am using python but merely looking for the approach and I can implement it.

Answer (score 1):

[Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) algorithms are designed to efficiently sample from very large data sets that may not fit into memory. There's an implementation provided with TensorFlow:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/backend/event_processing/reservoir.py